# SSH acess blocked after user was added to sftp group

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have a specific user and group associated to an SFTP service in my server.

recently I added my regular group to the group associated with the SFTP, and now I can no longer connect to the server via SSH. I get this message:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/administrador: No such file or directory
This service allows sftp connections only.
```

is there any work around this problem apart from physically logging in to the server and undoing the group association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any other user, who is able to log in and fix your configuration/groups over ssh, you need to log in locally (or using some web console).